# print out an pointer array from a double pointer function in main

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, double

This is from my .hpp file.

```
struct Item{
    std::string todo;};
const int MAX_STACK_SIZE = 5;
class StackArray
{
    public:
        StackArray();
        bool isEmpty();
        bool isFull();
        void push(std::string Item);
        void pop();
        Item* peek();
        int getStackTop() { return stackTop; }
        Item** getStack() { return stack; }
    private:
        int stackTop;
        Item* stack[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
};
#endif
```

And the following is part function from my .cpp file.

```
void StackArray::push(std::string Item)
{
    if (isFull())
    {
        cout<<"Stack full, cannot add new todo item."<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        stackTop++;
        Item* newStack = new Item[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
        newStack[stackTop].todo = Item;
    }
}
```

I really confused about printing out the stack array in main.cpp file. How can I do that? Here is now I got, but can only print out the address.

```
int main()
{
    StackArray stackArray;
    if (stackArray.isEmpty())
        cout<< "Empty stack." <<endl;
    stackArray.push("25");
    stackArray.push("20");
    stackArray.push("15");
    stackArray.push("10");

    Item**stack1=new Item*[5];
    *stack1=new Item;
    stack1=stackArray.getStack();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout<<*(stack1+i)<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're never saving `newStack` anywhere permanent, so you're leaking memory.

Comment: Why aren't you just adding the item to `stack`?

Comment: `cout<<stack1[i]->todo;` Except that it'll probably crash, because you never in fact initialize the contents of `StackArray::stack`; it contains random garbage.

Comment: using "cout<<stack1[i]->todo;" will get a seg fault.

Comment: Do I need to delete old stack after I assigned newStack in that function?

Comment: @Justinw You don't need `newStack` at all.

Comment: You can't delete `stack`, it's not allocated dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `push` method is never actually adding anything to the `stack`. It's allocating an entirely new array of pointers, but it's only assigned to a local variable, which goes away when the function ends. It should be adding the item to `stack`.

```
void TodoStackArray::push(std::string Item)
{
    if (isFull())
    {
        cout<<"Stack full, cannot add new todo item."<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        stackTop++;
        stack[stackTop] = new Item;
        stack[stackTop]->todo = Item;
    }
}
```

To print out the items, you need to indirect through the pointers.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << stack1[i]->todo << '\n';
}
```